# Java SecurityManager multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, security, securitymanager

I have been trying to use a custom SecurityManager to sandbox some externally loaded code. The SecurityManager I have works fine. I have taken the same approach as numerous posts here suggested: set the custom manager whenever the potentially dangerous code executes, then revert back to the standard manager. This works fine and does what I want. However, the application is multi-threaded: 2 threads using the custom manager, one using the default one. This leads to the situation where the trusted code might be prevented from running properly as another thread just set the custom security manager. Is there a way to work around this? Alternatively, is there a better way altogether? I saw some posts talking about using different policies with the same security manager but I could not find a good example of this. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which way round is this? Is it the externally loaded code that requires ( and is being granted ) the higher permissions?

Comment: The externally loaded code should have minimal permissions, the main code / main thread (which loads the external code) should have all permissions.

Comment: We had a similar problem too, as far as I know, the security manager is unique and shared for the entire VM and you cannot concurrently have different security managers. You would have to run some portions of your threaded code in synchronized blocks or something like that (ugly)

Comment: OK - my suggestion was going to be along the lines of Peter's below.

Comment: *I have taken the same approach as numerous posts here suggested: set the custom manager whenever the potentially dangerous code executes, then revert back to the standard manager.* Ughh, who has advised to do so? You can always determine the calling thread and the calling  AccessControlContext... that's how it should not be done (in a nutshell, setting/unsetting the SM is not the way to go)

Comment: Oh OK, there were a few posts here that suggested this (also a few examples elsewhere). I found the whole issue regarding security quite bewildering: unlike many other aspects of Java, security just does not seem to be that well documented.

Comment: @coderino - as noted in my answer below, this is actually quite extensively documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SecurityManager can check which thread is running.  A simple thread local will do this, however, you may want an InheritableThreadLocal so that any additional Threads created "inherit" the threads security level.

Comment: this seems "tricky" to get right.  presumably a given thread may operate in different contexts over time, so you need to propagate the current context when a new thread is launched (and probably not change it back with any changes to the old thread).  additionally, you need to worry about thread pools or other places where threads could be shared.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have now implemented something similar: the main thread "registers" those threads deemed untrusted (using their ids) and the checkPermission method in SecurityManger checks for the id of the calling thread. However, this does probably not work in case the untrusted code creates sub-threads. At the moment, this would not be allowed. But if it would be required, then the above method would likely fail.

Comment: @coderino - i don't know how long you maintain the thread ids, but beware that there is no guarantee that a thread id is unique for the lifetime of a jvm (as mentioned in the javadoc http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId%28%29 ).

Comment: Using `InheritableThreadLocal` solves the problem of sub-threads and non-unique thread names. You can call all your thread "main" and you can change it with Thread.setName().

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - ITL will work for directly spawned threads as long as the value is an immutable object (so that changing the parent thread's value does not change the child's value).  it doesn't solve the shared thread problem (e.g. thread pools).  ultimately, i still think it's preferable to use the java security architecture as designed, much less risk of "accidental" privilege leakage.  (also, the uniqueness problem is for thread ids, not names).

Comment: @jtahlborn, sure it does solve, and it should not share threads w/ the managed/unsecure application. I personally use thread groups (so does AWT and applet management) to determine the context. You can use the context class loader and an inherited AccessControlContext (you don't need the InheritableThreadLocal) since the AccessControlContext is inherited automatically.

Comment: @bestsss, I have used ThreadGroups in the past, but thought ITL might be simpler here. I wouldn't share thread pools between trusted/untrusted code either, but you could by wrapping execute() to set/unset the IRL on each invocation. :P

Comment: @Peter, ITL will be inherited even by some chance unsecure code managed to spawn a thread in secure code (like attempting to submit a legin task in ExecutorService), even though the thread can be considered secure it will have a bad trail that it can fix on its right own. ITL are hard to tackle imo.

Comment: @bestsss, Unless you are careful, an insecure thread can create a thread using a ThreadGroup from a secure thread. If you are really paranoid, don't run the un-trusted code in the same JVM. ;)

Comment: @Peter, I have established a rule that all threads must be created via some threadfactory (it takes care for ThreadGroup and CCL, naming and what not) or at the very least a thread group must be supplied.

Comment: @bestsss & @Peter - how do you handle code in finalizers?  presumably, a finalizer is run on some system thread.

Comment: @jhatlborn, The Finalizer Thread.  You shouldn't use finalizers if at all possible, but an insecure library could discard objects with dangerous code in their finalise() methods.

Comment: @jtahlborn, it is but you should grant permissions only to trusted code (unknown code is untrusted by default), also all system code (and your should follow) uses java.security.PrivilegedAction wrapper. Dont forget the permissions are granted by the codebase and in a SecurityManager you have getClassContext().

Comment: @Peter - that's exactly my point, another reason why i don't think using the current thread info is actually secure.

Comment: @bestsss - that doesn't make sense to me.  this answer is based on using the current thread to determine security, which i've been arguing is not actually secure.  i know it works just fine using standard codebase policies (which is why i said as much in my answer).

Comment: @jtahlborn, what doesn't make sense? the finalizer thread would enjoy extra security unless uses the PrivilegedAction. So basically you grant access on certain thread groups to simplify the example and can grant  extra access on codebase, if need be.

Comment: @bestsss - i think you are making the same point i am, which is basically that using thread info alone is _not_ sufficient for security, you need to use the policy and codebase support.

Answer (score 3):

You use one securitymanager for your entire application.  the java security framework was designed to handle this scenario.  the way you get things to work is using the codebases feature of the policy file, which enables you to assign different permissions to different codebases.  you can assign your "main" codebase "all permissions" and it will function as normal.  you can assign any imported code to a restricted codebase.

this is all heavily documented [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/), probably the part most relevant to this issue is the [policy file information](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html).

Comment: I will give this a go. Is there any good documentation on this including examples?

Comment: added links to the relevant sun/oracle documentation.

Comment: Great, thanks. I will go through these references to see what I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the current thread or removing security restrictions is not a good idea. **Just as a for instance**, suppose the untrusted code has a finaliser that likes to sleep?